# Is there an easy way to calculate the total cost of tolls for a trip within the United States?

Tags: usa, planning, driving, road-trips, tolls

Is there a convenient way to calculate the cost of tolls between two arbitrary points within the United States? I'm planning to take a trip along the Eastern seaboard and will be passing through multiple states with different toll-collecting authorities. The mapping and trip planning resources I've found so far will only indicate whether a particular section of road has tolls, not the price of those tolls. I'm aware that the various toll-collecting authorities post their rates online, but these charts are often difficult to use if you're not already familiar with the area. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: viamichelin.com seems to cover the US, only that every route I try, only mentions $0 in toll. Could either be that I just chose arbitrary roads with no tolls, or that this site does not include toll prices. Hence the comment over a real answer

Comment: @Andra I noticed this as well. I checked routes that definitely have tolls, so viamichelin.com is not accurate. :-(

Comment: Any chance you could list all the states? I'm finding some calculators but they seem to be per-state only, eg http://www.massdot.net/user-cgi/tollcalc.cgi for Massachusetts...

Comment: @MarkMayo I found those as well. Part of my trip will take me through MD, DE, PA, NJ, and NY. I've learned that several states (DE and NY, for example) even have different toll-collecting authorities for the different routes. I was hoping to find a single calculator that would be able to compute the cost based on the portions of the route I will be using, but I suppose it's just a dream.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised Google Maps doesn't do it.

Comment: Illinois has a [virtual tollway](https://www.illinoisvirtualtollway.com/) site that will compute total tolls on a given route, but it doesn't seem to provide a way to export the toll locations and prices for use in other apps. @AndrewGrimm I imagine Google Maps would include it only if they could get up-to-date toll prices from *every* tollway provider on demand.

Comment: Keep in mind: some areas have tolls with variable rates due to time of day and traffic conditions. Many places also require you to have a transponder (or pay an excess fee), since there are no longer stations for collecting tolls.

Answer (score 16):

If you know your route, you could use [Tollsmart.com](http://calculator.tollsmart.com/) (paywall, $2 minimum) or their [free mobile app](https://www.tollsmart.com/free-toll-calculator/):

Sample:

> CALIFORNIA
>
> 17-Mile Drive   Toll: $9.25 Location:  Scenic drive through Pebble
> Beach, CA Operator: Pebble Beach Corporation
>
> Golden Gate Bridge   Toll: $6.00 (Southbound ONLY) Location:  Spans
> San Francisco Bay connecting San Francisco to Marin County, CA
> Operator: Golden Gate Bridge, Highway & Transportation District
>
> Riverside Freeway (SR-91)   Toll: Variable Location: An east-west
> freeway in Southern California linking Orange and Riverside counties
> Operator: Orange County Transportation Authority (OCTA)
>
> Eastern Transportation Corridor   Toll: $3.50 (East Branch) $3.25
> (West Branch) Location: Orange County, CA Operator: Foothill/Eastern
> Transportation Corridor Agency
>
> South Bay Expressway   Toll: Variable Location: Beginning at Otay
> Mesa, provides access to/from Mexico and across San Diego Operator:
> South Bay Expressway, L.P.
>
> The Antioch Bridge   Toll: $5.00 (Northbound ONLY) Location:  Spans
> the San Joaquin River linking Antioch, CA with Sacramento County, CA
> Operator: Bay Area Toll Authority Metropolitan Transportation
> Commission
>
> The Benicia-Martinez Bridge   Toll: $5.00 (Northbound ONLY) Location:
> Spans the Carquinez Strait linking Benicia, CA to Martinez, CA
> Operator: Bay Area Toll Authority Metropolitan Transportation
> Commission

you get the idea.

Comment: Mark Mayo - The above linked website is ¿now? only half way towards the ideal/what i believe the OP is asking for (automatic calculation of tolls based on route). The information that is available on it only goes one better than the lists of prices already available via toll agencies/organisations website, by collating them onto one site (hopefully being updated regularily). As an aside, if you are open to edit suggestions, I have 2: 1) Re-word the preluding sentence to the yellow box, to make it seem to some less like the following is auto calculated, but instead just self-compiled.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is a cool app "TollGuru" that can tell you toll cost for all possible routes in United States. It calculates cheapest, fastest and other route options based on total cost (gas and toll cost) and time of your drive based on current traffic. And best part is that you can customize it for your vehicle. It covers all toll roads and bridges in United States.

Comment: In addition to being a mobile app, [TollGuru](https://tollguru.com/) also has a web app! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

The phone application [Waze](https://www.waze.com/) gives toll price estimates:

[image]

When viewing alternative routes:

[image]

Comment: @Willeke it's well documented that the majority of drivers don't respect the posted limits because they are too low. Therefore in practice speed traps are akin to a toll.

Comment: I would not mind if you mentioned that the site/app will tell you about speed limits (and that there are often traps) but I do not accept you calling those limits and traps tolls. (And there might be other reasons for low speed limits you can not easily see, or on times you are not there.)

Comment: I don't know if this is a fairly recent addition to Waze, but it wasn't there 3 years ago when I last hit toll roads in Chicago. It did come in handy around Denver and through OK on a road trip this summer. Also, I agree with your removed comments, @FranckDernoncourt. I used to call that the "random tax". Unfortunately, the mod comment is valid - not everyone gets the sarcasm. :/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  The majority of drivers in the US don't respect speed limits because they are not enforced or only enforced capriciously.  You can drive down an interstate in the US doing 10% over the limit and the cops won't even look at you (assuming not a speed blitz weekend).  Compare with Australia where you can be dinged for for both instantaneous  2% over the limit, or also dinged for your *average* speed being too high on some highways (they image you at one spot and then compare how long it took to get to the next camera)

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps app (free) shows the estimated toll price for most routes:

[image: Georgia to Ohio: $8.19]

It will sometimes just say "tolls", but I've found that breaking up the route will help you see the actual cost (e.g., Seattle, WA to Billings, MT — no tolls; Billings to Ohio — $6.61).

Comment: This only works by adding up all you find on the screen. Do you have a way to do it automatically ?

Comment: @Willeke I don't understand what you're asking. Isn't it done automatically in my screenshot?

Comment: In the question they ask for an easy way to calculate the total till for a long journey, you mention that you get the toll cost when you cut the travel to a short one.

Comment: @Willeke For all the traveling I've done personally (less than 3 hour trips), it just worked automatically. I just noticed it doesn't work for some long routes and found a workaround.