# Is there an automated way to find tolls on a given US/Canadian driving route?

Tags: usa, canada, maryland, ontario, tolls

To my knowledge the only way to estimate the toll for a route, i.e. from Baltimore, Maryland, USA to Guelph, Ontario, Canada, is as follows.

1. Get the list of highways route info from Google maps.
2. Go to the website of each authority.
3. For each highway, research the entry and exit points from Google map and related them to the authority defined regions.
4. List the tolls from the authority defined regions and sum them up.

I don't want anyone else to do this for me. I can do it by myself. But is there any easier way? Can anyone at least give me a rough estimate like whether it is around $50, $100, $150? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  When searching for the route you should just select option : Avoid Tolls and your toll burden becomes $0

Comment: @Karlson: That actually doesn't work in this case.  It routes you over the [Whirlpool Rapids bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_Rapids_Bridge) which also has a toll (though unbeknownst to Google) and moreover is only open to [NEXUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXUS_%28frequent_traveller_program%29) members.  Also, the route is 20 minutes longer.

Comment: Are you asking for the toll for this specific journey, or for a resource that calculates tolls in the US and Canada for any route?

Comment: @drat That should have been *[Is there an easy way to calculate the total cost of tolls for a trip within the United States?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9204)*. Unfortunately, the site in the selected answer (http://beta.costtodrive.com/us-tolls/ ) seems much more limited compared to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google route shows tolls for three consecutive segments of that route, but actually it's just one toll: at the [Peace Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_Bridge).  The toll is roughly $3.

Comment: I just passed on it about a month ago, and it was 4$. Guess it increased since 2014.