# Trip to Canada by car

Tags: usa, canada, international-travel, road-trips, tolls

I would like to know how many tolls are between Maryland and Canada. Planning a road trip to Niagara Falls, Canada and need to know how much in tolls I'll need to pay?

Comment: Which route are you taking ?

Comment: Also do you have E-ZPass or not?

Comment: And for completeness, what kind of vehicle are you driving?

Comment: Try http://beta.costtodrive.com/us-tolls/ as suggested in *[Is there an easy way to calculate the total cost of tolls for a trip within the United States?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9204)* You have not given us enough details to give you more than that.

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with Canada

Comment: I fail to see the need for this question given that option of "Avoid Tolls" can produce a route with no tolls.  The only thing is that all bridges to Ontario from the US side have tolls as far as I know.

Comment: Drive http://www.camillc.com/Site/images/HT/ht_exit2.jpg this,  avoid bridges. :P Or the OP really should've told us what they drive.