# What tools are available to calculate the costs of tolls when planning a road trip in USA?

Tags: online-resources, driving, road-trips, maps, tolls

I am plotting a road trip using google maps.

On some routes it says "this routes has tolls"

Are there any means by which I can see where the tolls are and their prices?

EDIT: It has been determined that Via Michelin does not work with USA tolls.

Comment: AFAIK Google doesn't have this information - it can depend on many factors such as the type of vehicle, number of passengers, time of day, traffic conditions, etc.  In general you have to look up the tolls with the agency that operates that particular road.  But if you're in the US, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/is-there-an-easy-way-to-calculate-the-total-cost-of-tolls-for-a-trip-within-the?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

When tolls are involved, I usually rely on [Via Michelin](http://viamichelin.com) in combination with google maps. Via Michelin allows you to calculate the total cost of the tolls, as well as an estimate of fuel costs given your vehicle type and the price of the fuel. For example, planning a road trip from Paris to Milan shows the total cost of tolls at the bottom:

[image: Via Michelin road plan tolls]

Looking at the detailed itinerary also shows you the cost of the individual portions of the trip:

[image]

Comment: This application is not congruent with google maps. For example from Weehawken, NJ to Atlantic City, NJ, google maps says there are tolls and viamichelin says there are not.

Comment: @ScottF:  Trying to plot a trip from Boston, MA, USA to Buffalo, NY, USA yields the same discrepancy, and there are definitely tolls along that route.  My guess is that Michelin's toll information doesn't include the USA.

Comment: I can confirm that it isn't including USA tolls, as I chose a route that I know locally as tolled, and confirmed the projected route took it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps can tell you which portions of a route have tolls, although it doesn't tell you what the toll amounts are.  To find this information, select a route and click on the blue "DETAILS" link.  Then click on the chevrons on the right to show the detailed lists of directions.  The segments of the trip that have tolls will be clearly marked.

[image]