# Given a path driven in the US, how can I get the list of websites where I can pay the toll fees incurred during the drive?

Tags: usa, driving, fees-and-charges

Given a path driven in the United States, how can I get the list of websites where I can pay the toll fees incurred during the drive?

E.g. https://www.bayareafastrak.org/en/tolls/ggb-pay-online.shtml or https://thetollroads.com/.

I'd prefer not to rely on road signs (sometimes easy to miss or forget), e.g.

[image]

([image source](https://thetollroadsblog.com/2014/04/29/signs-on-the-toll-roads-are-going-purple/))

---

https://tollguru.com/toll-calculator doesn't indicate the websites where one can pay the toll fees, e.g. https://tollguru.com/tolls/Lincoln%2CNE-Chicago%2CIL/900ebd2a-b9a4-4f76-af6c-b7332cfdcd40:

[image]

https://calculator.tollsmart.com/ also doesn't indicate the websites where one can pay the toll fees:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to calculate the total cost of tolls for a trip within the United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/is-there-an-easy-way-to-calculate-the-total-cost-of-tolls-for-a-trip-within-the)

Comment: @choster thanks, https://calculator.tollsmart.com/ and https://tollguru.com/toll-calculator don't indicate the websites where one can pay the toll fees. (and the question is different)

Comment: Are all of the toll roads you wish to travel on covered by the EZ-Pass system? If not, there is no one stop shop for that. Sounds like an idea for a new app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is currently no solution to get the list of websites where one can pay the toll fees incurred during the drive. There is a [large amount of toll systems in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_electronic_toll_collection_systems&oldid=981192791#United_States) and they aren't compatible, so the toll situation in the US is a mess:

> The 2012 transportation funding bill [MAP-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_Ahead_for_Progress_in_the_21st_Century_Act) required all electronic tolling systems on Interstate highways be compatible by October 1, 2016, but no funding and no penalty were provided, so discussions on interoperability are ongoing[[38]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_electronic_toll_collection_systems&oldid=981192791#cite_note-ajc-38) through the International Bridge, Tunnel and Turnpike Association.[[39]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_electronic_toll_collection_systems&oldid=981192791#cite_note-39) In [Florida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida), older battery-powered SunPass transponders were no longer accepted as of January 1, 2016, in preparation for future compatibility with E-ZPass toll booths. Several [mobile tolling platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Mobile_Tolling_Platforms) are currently in use.

Comment: Someone might have made one you do not yet know about. Accepting this answer is not wise.

Comment: @Willeke I'll happily accept another answer.